# State is undefined when using the Redux store in React

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I have this configuration when using react-redux connect().

```
 const mapStateToProps = state => ({
      ...state
    });
    const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => ({
      addMessage: msg => dispatch(addMessage(msg))
    });

    export default connect(
      mapStateToProps,
      mapDispatchToProps
    )(RoomChat);
```

When using `this.props.chats` I am getting `"TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined"`.

This is the state, an array of objects that have the fields of 'username' and 'content':

```
chats = [{ content: '', username: '' }]
```

It is define in the RoomChat.js like this:

```
  this.state = {
      chats: []
    };
```

This is the store.js where the redux store is defined:

```
import { createStore } from 'redux';
import MessageReducer from './reducers/MessageReducer';
function configureStore(chats = [{ content: '', username: '' }]) {
  return createStore(MessageReducer, chats);
}
export default configureStore;
```

Reducer:

```
export default (state, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'addMessage':
      return {
        content: action.text,
        username: 'R'
      };
    default:
      return state;
  }
};
```

action:

```
export function addMessage(text) {
  return { type: 'addMessage', text };
}
```

What went wrong here ?, I have tried multiple configurations without success so far

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `mapStateToProps` function, you need to do this...

```
const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  chats: state
});
```

This is because you're creating your store with the `chats` array when you do `createStore(MessageReducer, chats)`.

So the `state` is automatically `chats`

**UPDATE**
In addition to @smoak's comment, you need to update your reducer like this

```
export default (state, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'addMessage':
      return [
        ...state,
        {
          content: action.text,
          username: 'R'
        }
      ];
    default:
      return state;
  }
};
```

Comment: It am still getting the same error, I added the reducer and action.. Maybe the problem is there ?

Comment: can you try again? I just updated the `mapStateToProps` function because I wrote `chat` instead of `chats`

Comment: This is it right here, `state = [{ content: '', username: '' }]` so when you spread state in `mapStateToProps` you're left with: `[{content: '', username: '' }]` which isn't a plain object.

Comment: Yeah, that eliminated the error. Thanks. Though I am not getting the content inside chats - content, after using the action :"this.props.addMessage("hello");"

Comment: smoak, What should I do instead ?

Comment: can you update the question with your `RoomChat.js` component? So it's easier to figure out what's going on?

Comment: That sounds like a separate question, but I will attempt to help you here. Your reducer is returning new state which is an object, but your initial state is just an array.

Comment: Updated my answer with @smoak's comment

Answer (score 0):

Mabye try this
`const mapStateToProps = state => {return {chats: state.chats}};`
or this
`const mapStateToProps = state => { return {...state}};`
You need to return object in mapStateToProps and mapDistpachToProps.